# Algorithm that numpy is using for `numpy.linalg.lstsq`

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I am doing some linear algebra and I noticed that `numpy.linalg.lstsq()` is doing what I need.  I assume that `np.linalg.lstsq()` is using a built-in algorithm from LAPACK or something.

**What algorithm is `numpy.linalg.lstsq` using?**

---

For some background, assume that I have a matrix `A` that has more columns than rows.  For example:

```
import numpy
A = numpy.random.randn(4, 5)
print(numpy.linalg.lstsq(A, A))
```

The resulting printed value happens to be equivalent to the following formula:

```
A.T.dot(np.linalg.inv(A.dot(A.T))).dot(A)
```

If I calculate `numpy.linalg.lstsq(A, A)` as above I would expect to get the identity matrix.  However, it is giving another value.

`numpy.linalg.lstsq` is obviously not using the formula for [linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis#Linear_regression), because `np.linalg.inv(A.T.dot(A))` is not computable because `A.T.dot(A)` is singular.

You can see from [my post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2313648/algorithm-for-inverse-of-x-cdot-xt) on math.stackexchange.com that I am searching for another way to calculate the above algorithm.

EDIT: I am not looking for a way to calculate the identity matrix.  I am looking to copy the LAPACK formula that `numpy.linalg.lstsq` is using.  Look at my older post above for background information.

Comment: A short code-read [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.13.0/numpy/linalg/linalg.py#L1949): it's based on [dgelsd](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-3.1.1-html/dgelsd.f.html)

Comment: But you probably want [the cholesky-approach](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.cholesky.html).